# I want to use keyvalue pipe without receive an id from the object

Tags: html, angular, pipe

I want to use keyvalue pipe without receive an id from the object.
How can it achieve it ?

```
        <div *ngFor="let outerObject of outerObject$ | async ;index as i">
                    <div *ngFor="let innerObject of innerObject |  keyvalue">

                    </div>
        </div>
```

object => include an id inside and more some properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`KeyValuePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) only allows to define a compare function in order to sort the keys. So you could have a getter in the TypeScript file:

```
get filteredObject() {
  const { id, ...rest } = this.object;
  return rest;
}
```

Or even this:

```
get filteredObject() {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(this.object).filter(([key]) => key !== 'id'));
}
```

And then in the template:

```
*ngFor="let myBbject of filteredObject | keyvalue
```

**Edit:**

Given your `object` comes from an `Observable` (let's say `outerObject$`), then you have to do the transform operation inside a `.pipe(...)` like this:

```
this.outerObject$ = this.someService.someFunction().pipe(
  map(x => x.map(y => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(y).filter(([key]) => key !== 'id')))));
```

Comment: yes i know but i can't edit that object with type script because i receive that object with pipe - let object of object$ | async -

Comment: Ok can you edit your question and add more relevant code so I can provide a solution?

Comment: Just convert it to to a function accepts desired object as parameter